# Is this proof of convergence in probability correct?

Tags: real-analysis, probability, probability-theory, proof-verification, convergence-divergence

${X_i}, i = 1,2,\dots$ i.i.d random variables, and $S_n = \sum_{i=1}^nX_i$ is defined as partial sum as usual. If

$\frac{S_n}{n} \to 0 \quad $ in probability

show that

$$\lim_{n\to \infty} \min_{1\leq k \leq n}\mathbb{P}\left(\frac{\left|S_n - S_k\right|}{n} < \epsilon\right) = 1 .$$

My proof:

[image]

Is this proof correct? Can I just fix k and claiming it is uniformly convergent?
Thanks in advanced.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem in the presented proof is that it only show that for any fixed $k$, $\lim_{n\to +\infty}\mathbb P\left(\left|S_n-S_k\right|/n\gt\varepsilon \right)= 0$, which is not hard to see from the convergence in probability of $\left(S_n/n\right)_{n\geqslant 1}$ to $0$. We actually have to prove that $\lim_{n\to +\infty}\color{red}{\max_{1\leqslant k\leqslant n}}\mathbb P\left(\left|S_n-S_k\right|/n\gt\varepsilon \right)= 0$, which is a stronger property.

A proof [is given in this thread](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1833865/an-ancillary-result-from-convergence-in-probability).